# Opening New Window for Every Iteration, Selenium

Tags: python, windows, selenium, iteration

I am trying to loop through a list of string coordinates to navigate to a specific google earth page. I want a new window opened and the previous closed for each iteration and also need to switch to the new window. I am not sure how to make Selenium open a new window with each iteration, can someone explain how to do this?

Right now if I loop through these coordinates the second iteration is directed to a different page and puts me in a kind of infinite loop, but seems to work fine when the window is initially opened, hence why I want to open multiple windows.

Thanks for your help.

```

```
width, height = get_screen_res()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])


for i, c in enumerate(coordinates):
    filepath = '../images/Jafay/' + str(i) + '.png'
    lat, lon = c.split(',')
    url = 'http://earth.google.com/web/@{},{},1615.83371101a,196.41606213d,35y,0h,0t,0r'.format(lat, lon)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.save_screenshot(filepath)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line. Don't use `driver.close()` inside the loop, use it when you finish the script. You also don't need to set the screen size when using `maximize_window()` and don't need to use `switch_to_window()` as you have only one window in this point

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

for i, c in enumerate(coordinates):
    filepath = '../images/Jafay/' + str(i) + '.png'
    lat, lon = c.split(',')
    url = 'http://earth.google.com/web/@{},{},1615.83371101a,196.41606213d,35y,0h,0t,0r'.format(lat, lon)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.save_screenshot(filepath)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I wanted it to switch to make sure it was on the proper screen before taking a screenshot. Simple mistakes are the worst.